# PHP file path from Command Line different

Tags: php, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

If I run this simple code through the browser, it works normally and creates 'text.txt' in the same location as the script.

```
 <?php

    $op = fopen('text.txt', 'w');

    fwrite($op, 'test');

    fclose($op)

    ?>
```

But if I run with command line

```
php script.php
```

it creates the file in a completely different directory.

Why does the same script behave differently by running the browser and the command line ?!

To fix this I need to put the full path: `fopen('/home/user/site.com/subfolder/text.txt', 'w');`

I have a script with many lines and many file paths, it would be too much work to change all. How can I fix this problem without putting the complete path in the file.

Comment: From where are you running the command? is the file created in the directory where you ran your command?

Comment: when you run your code via browser it runs on web server `apache or others`, when you run your code from shell it runs by `php interpreter`
read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: I'm running directly from the shell

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov Is it possible to do some global configuration. So that they work the same way?

Comment: it is better to write full path rather than to edit php `ini` file!

Comment: It should be working in the same directory you're using to run the command. check your environment. try getcwd() inside the script

Comment: just open terminal in folder where your script is located and run your script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal and type:

```
cd /home/user/site.com/subfolder
```

then run:

```
php script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

start_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /to/location/of/script
php script.php
```